# How to integrate jsReport in angular 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api, jsreport

I am unable to get started. I need to integrate jsReport with angular 5.
I am currently working on Application which is based on Anuglar 5 and Asp.Net webapi

Comment: Could you please add more details , like what you have tried & what exactly issue you are facing ?

Answer (score 3):

`jsreport` need server render, it self use node express see [here](https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-express).

They are have a studio like app boilerplate, to try on the local, see [here](https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport).

If you want to use integrate with angular, you can refer [jsreport-browser-client](https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-browser-client), See [documentation](https://jsreport.net/learn/browser-client) for more information.

> The script itself should be compatible with webpack, requirejs and other script bundlers.

```
jsreport.serverUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';

var request = {
  template: {
    content: 'foo', engine: 'none', recipe: 'phantom-pdf'
   }
};

//display report in the new tab
jsreport.render('_blank', request);

//display report in placeholder with id reportPlaceholder
jsreport.render('reportPlaceholder', request);

//display report in placeholder element
jsreport.render(document.getElementById('reportPlaceholder'), request);

//open download dialog for report
jsreport.download('myReport.pdf', request);
```

This sample code, you can put to your `angular`, need more modification.
in first line `jsreport.serverUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';` need listen jsreport express (node express).

**TL;DR;**
So you just need run 2 app:

- jsreport server which node express ([Documentation](https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-express))
- your main app angular + asp.net which install `jsreport-browser-client` ([Documentation](https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-browser-client))

Comment: hi @hendrathings, you have any example of jsreport integrated in angular 6 or brief of integration with angula 6